# How can I display dialog list in web browser (HTML) so that user can select information from Address Book in Lotus Notes

Tags: jquery, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, agent

Before this I ask a question how to display Address Book through web browser in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57305155/9688943). Then, I found an Agent that can run and find all information in Address Book. But my problem right now is, I do not know how to display a dialog list so that User can choose any information.

My Agent is as below:

```
books = s.AddressBooks
foundflag = False
ForAll b In books
    If b.FileName="names.nsf" Then
        Call b.Open( "", "" )
        Set view = b.GetView( "People" )
        Call view.Refresh
        foundflag = True
        Exit ForAll
    End If
End ForAll

If Not foundflag Then
    returnVal = "NSF file not found."
    GoTo endp
End If

count = 0
Set tmpdoc = view.GetFirstDocument
Do While Not tmpdoc Is Nothing
    If tmpdoc.MailFile(0) <> "" _
    And tmpdoc.MailAddress(0) = "" _
    And tmpdoc.InternetAddress(0)<>"" Then
        count = count + 1
        tmpstr = tmpdoc.LastName(0)
        If tmpstr="" Then tmpstr = tmpdoc.FirstName(0)
        tmplist(count) = tmpstr & "|@|" & tmpdoc.InternetAddress(0)
    End If
    Set tmpdoc = view.GetNextDocument(tmpdoc)
Loop

If count=0 Then
    returnVal = "No employee were found"
    GoTo endp
End If
```

I have my jQuery that can call this agent but I can't figure out how to display the list in HTML. My jQuery is as below:

```
$.post("http://server/pcspec.nsf/jsonEmpList?OpenAgent",
    function(data, status) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(data);
        if (arr.status == "success") {
            $(arr.items).each(function(i, item) {
                $("#PUserID").append('<option value="' + item.mail + '">' + item.name + ' (' + item.mail + ')</option>');
            });
        } else {
            alert(arr.message);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("ERROR - " + xhr + " - " + status + " - " + error);
    })
```

So my question is, how can I prompt dialog list in web browser for user to make a selection. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can't just use a Domino field Dialog List field with "Use formula for choices" and have the formula @DbColumn("":"";"Server/Domain":"names.nsf";"People";2) ?  That won't work for your application?

Comment: A third option would be to add a view in the address book that has all the name records already formatted in JSON, or even with the HTML you need for a select list, and then just do a GET on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking "How do I get information back from an agent to jQuery", the answer is the PRINT statement.  I get an error with your use of the AddressBooks so I hardcoded the public address book's name.  But this snippet will return a JSON object.  Of course you'll need to declare the appropriate variables and set the server name accordingly.

```
Set db = s.getDatabase("server/document","names.nsf",False)
If db Is nothing Then
    print "ERROR: Names.nsf not found</br>"
    exit sub
End If
Set view=db.getView("People")
Set tmpdoc = view.GetFirstDocument
Do While Not tmpdoc Is Nothing
    If tmpdoc.MailFile(0) <> "" _
    And tmpdoc.MailAddress(0) = "" _
    And tmpdoc.InternetAddress(0)<>"" Then
        tmpStr = ToJSON(tmpdoc)
        Print tmpStr + "<br />"
    End If
    Set tmpdoc = view.GetNextDocument(tmpdoc)
Loop
```

The result:

```
{"value": "CN=John Doe/O=ACME", "text": "john.doe@acme.com"}
{"value": "CN=Jane Smith/O=ACME", "text": "jane.smith@acme.com"}
```

Comment: Hi @Duston , I can display as your answer, but it just display all names in names.nsf. I want to able to select. Also I try you suggestion in comment for @DbColumn("":"";"Server/Domain":"names.nsf";"People";2) , but nothing happened.

Comment: Right, my answer doesn't put the items in to the list box, you have to do that in your jQuery.  But your jQuery wants a JSON reply, my code is a JSON reply.  You can take it from there.

Comment: WRT @DbColumn(..)  Did you put your values for the server name and address book, or did you just copy/paste my code?

Comment: No I'm not copy and paste. I write something like this @DbColumn("":"";"www.me.com.my":"names.nsf";"People";2) . Is there something I'm missing out?

Comment: The server name is the server as it would be known to a Notes client (or server) not the browser.  The "Domain" is the Notes domain, not the DNS domain.  And as long as the address book is called "Names.nsf" (there's no guarantee that it is) that part is right.

Comment: Hello. I try again your solution using @DbColumn and it work well. I use @DbColumn("":"";"":"names.nsf";"People";5). 5 is represent email in my names.nsf database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar earlier tonight. But my approach is somewhat different. In my case, I am using the plugin [Select2](https://select2.org/) for the dropdown field, where the user selects a person from the list.

```js
// Initialize Select2 dropdown
$('[data-dropdown="names"]').select2({
  allowClear: true,
  theme: 'bootstrap',
  width: '100%',
  minimumResultsForSearch: 20,
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  delay: 450,
  ajax: {
    url: "/agents/getContactList.json?OpenAgent",
    dataType: "json",
    data: function(params) {
      var query = {
        term: params.term
      };
      return query;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="selectContact">Contact Name</label>
  <select id="selectContact" class="form-control input-sm dominoDropdown" data-placeholder="">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The Select2 dropdown is populated through an Ajax call to a Lotusscript agent, which returns all names partially matching what is entered in the dropdown. You could of course also load all the data up-front, but depending on the number of documents in the NAB, it may be slow.

Below is the code for the Lotusscript agent. It is using my own classes for URL query string parsing and JSON generation, but in Domino 10 you have classes built-in. I have simplified the code somewhat by removing a number of extra options I am using.

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Use "Class.JSON"
Use "Class.URL"

Sub Initialize
    '--- Local Notes classes used in agent
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim col As NotesViewEntryCollection
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim columns As Variant 
    Dim column As NotesViewColumn
    Dim entry As NotesViewEntry
    '--- Custom classes
    Dim json As JSONData
    Dim url As New URLData()
    '--- Local variables
    Dim jsontxt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim value As String
    Dim filtervalue As String
    Dim id As String
    Dim options As String
    Dim lookupview As String
    Dim query As String  
    '*** Get document
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    lookupview = "(lookup_Contacts)"
    Set view = db.GetView(lookupview)
    If view Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Contact view not found"
        Exit Sub 
    End If
    Call view.Refresh()
    jsontxt = "[ "
    '*** Get all entries in view
    Set col = view.AllEntries()
    '*** Reduce the collection using a full-text search
    query = |[LastName] CONTAINS *| & url.GetValue("term") & |* OR [FirstName] CONTAINS *| & url.GetValue("term") & |*|
    Call col.FTSearch(query,0)

    If col Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "col is nothing!"
        Exit Sub 
    End If
    '*** Loop through view entries and build the JSON to return
    Set entry = col.GetFirstEntry()
    Do Until entry Is Nothing
        value = CStr(entry.ColumnValues(3)) ' Name to display
        If InStr(LCase(value),LCase(filtervalue))>0 Then
            id = CStr(entry.ColumnValues(2))    ' UNID
            Set json = New JSONdata()
            Call json.NoStatus()
            Call json.SetValue("id", id)
            Call json.SetValue("text", value)
            jsontxt = jsontxt + json.GetJSON() + ","
        End If
        Set entry = col.GetNextEntry(entry)
    Loop 

    '*** Remove trailing comma 
    If Len(jsontxt)>4 Then
        jsontxt = Left$(jsontxt, Len(jsontxt)-1)
    End If
    jsontxt = jsontxt + " ]"
    '*** MIME Header to tell browser what kind of data we will return (Javascript).
    '*** See http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt
    Print "content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8"
    Print |{ "results": |+jsontxt+| }|
End Sub
```

This is the end result:
[image: Picture of dropdown field]

***Update 2019-09-03:*** Screen shot of the view used for lookup by agent
[image: Screen shot showing the view used for the lookup]

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Karl thank you for this. Will look forward to it. I will get back when I get the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Karl, I forgot to ask you yesterday. You said you use URL query string parsing and JSON generation with your own class. Also I'm still using Domino 9 so I don't have any build in classes. I just wonder where can I get URL and JSON classes? Another question is, in jQuery you use `data-dropdown="names"` , I don't really understand how to integrate between jQuery and the select.

Comment: I posted both the HTTP and the JSON classes on my blog. If you shoot me an email I can send you a .NSF containing the latest versions. All info is on my profile.

Comment: Hi @Karl, I implement your suggestion answer but I still cannot display the name from names.nsf. I also include your URL and JSON classes but still it just blank dropdown.

Comment: Have you verified that the agent returns the correct JSON payload? And you modified the agent to point to your names.nsf and a view in the correct format? In my example, the first column in the view is categorized (the type of contact), then there is a hidden column with the last name sorted, next the UNID of the contact (used as the id of the option) and then in column 3 (the column count starts with 0) I have the name to display in the dropdown.
I am inserting a screenshot of the view in my response.